# CTabFolderRenderer

Tags: java, eclipse, tabs, swt

I need to customize my swt tabfolder. The problem specifically is :

```
if( a condition met in the content of a tab item )

{

    color the upper tab area of that tab item

}

if( tabfolder to be reset )

{

    reset the tabfolder back to its original view

}
```

I think a `CTabFolderRenderer`  can do it? Any ideas/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, writing your own CTabFolderRenderer and setting it to your CTabFolder instance is an option.

Yet, CTabFolder's `setBackground(Color color)` and `setSelectionBackground(Color color)` methods would work for you if your aim is just to color the tab item.

Comment: Thanks. But setSelectionBackground(Color color) would draw every tab that is selected with that color? Using a CTabFolderRenderer can I get individual control on tab items?

Comment: Indeed `setSelectionBackground(Color color)` would draw every tab that is selected with specified color. I'm not sure though, whether you can get individual item control with CTabFolderRenderer (in theory it makes sense though). Another option would be overriding the `setSelectionBackground(Color color)` method to control individual tab items.